# Read a Json File on S3 and return it on LAMBDA

Tags: json, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

On my Lambda function I want to read a JSON File on S3 and dynamically return it as a JavaScript Object.

For example, I want to call the Lambda Function with some parameters (e.g. Bucket Name and File-Path) then I would receive the content as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3({region: 'your-region'});

module.exports.s3json = async (event, context) => {
    let bucket = event.bucket || 'your-bucket';
    let file = event.filename || 'your-file-path';

    let data = await s3.getObject({
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: file
    }).promise();
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.parse(data.Body.toString())
    };
};
```